# Search posts with specific combination of tags

Tags: support, tags, search, tag-search

Let’s say I want to obtain a list of all topics that have tags `[x] & [y]`, but not `[z]`.

For example, let’s say a topic has the below tags `[x] & [y]`. Then I should have this topic in my search list.

But let’s say a topic has the below tags `[x] & [z]`. Then I should not have this topic in my search list. Similarly, topics with all `[x], [y], & [z]` will also be excluded.

Is there a way to get a list of topics with the above criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "the following tags" option in a custom filter:

[image: Tagged with The following tags: x y not z]

If you want more power, this fills the search bar with a search, so you can search within those questions (and answers) for keywords or other advanced operators.

Comment: How can I further modify this criteria only to show the topics having `at least one answers`?

Comment: @augustine Find the search bar at the top while you're in the filter and add `answers:1`